# TP-Link USB Wi-Fi dongle won't detect any wireless networks

Tags: network, wifi, usb, high-sierra, virtualization

This is the second Wi-Fi card I am trying, so I am confident that it is not the card in question that is not working correctly.

I have macOS High Sierra running 10.13.5 with a TP-Link Archer T4UH with the official drivers installed from TP's website.

Everything appears to be in working order, however no matter what I do I cannot get the network to display.

I am running Mac OS X in a **VM**. But to my mind this shouldn't make any difference at all.

I pass the `usb dongle` directly into the Guest. No longer having access to this device in the host.

Below is what I see:

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Update**

After using an older version of OSx I have got the wireless to work internally.

[image]

Showing my setup

[image]

Comment: You simply ***cannot** virtualize a network adapter in VirtualBox.  You must use the host and then use one of the virtual *wired* network adapters provided by VirtualBox.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @Allan indeed, I will update the question. I am passing the usb device directly to the VM

Comment: *I am passing the usb device directly to the VM* - I'm not sure what you didn't understand in my first comment, but **you cannot do this.**.  In other words, it will not work.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I agree with @Allan and suspect your question may indicate an XY problem. That is, you have a problem (X) and decide the solution is Y, and when you can't quite get Y to work you've come here asking a question about Y rather than the actual problem X. I've posted an answer to try and explain in more detail what Allan was indicating to you, and perhaps (hopefully) it will also help you achieve your ultimate goal.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more images.

Comment: Ah, yes, your edit certainly clarifies things now! :) I note you haven't clarified what virtualisation software you're using and I think this will be relevant in terms of finding any possible solutions for you. I've never used a USB network adapter in this way, but have used a whole heap of other USB devices and have found that how well they work within virtual machine environments is a bit hit and miss. Sometimes you *can* try to configure things to improve compatibility, but knowing what virtualisation software you're using is a must.

Comment: Things are actually working. I am using VMPlayer :) So I am not sure what would cause the USB card to not work, but the problem was/is somehow dependant on the version of OSx, but only at the point of driver installation.  I start with 10.12/13 and it would display the original issue. However if i start on 10.10.. it works, then upgrade to 12/13 and it still works :? Sad but true

Comment: @JamieHutber Thanks for sharing what worked for you. I'm sure this will help others too! :)

Answer (score 2):

As Allan has mentioned in the comments, what you're trying to do (or perhaps *how* you're trying to approach this) is not possible.

Let's assume you're using Parallels (if not, it doesn't matter - this is just an example). And let's assume you're running Parallels on an iMac and you've installed Windows 10 on a virtual machine (again, an example - I know you're talking about an OS X guest).

Now, for the guest OS (regardless of what it is) to access the internet or a network, it **needs** to access that network via the host in some way. Typically you'll have options for using a *Shared*, *Bridged* or *Host-only network*. **All of these still require the network (or adapter) to be running on the host machine.**

Some tips:

- If your goal is to connect to the internet from your guest machine, then you wouldn't use the *Host-only* (or equivalent) option.
- If what you're trying to do is have your virtual machine treated as a stand-alone computer on the network and configured in the same way as a real one, then you'd use the *Bridged network* option. This allows your guest to access the network and internet using the adapter you've connected to the internet (assuming you've set this up properly on the host machine). **Just to be clear, the adapter must be installed, recognised and running on the host machine!**
- If you're wanting your guest to share all the network connections available on the host machine (including the internet), then just choose the *Shared Network* (or equivalent) option.

In my case I always use the Shared Network option in my virtual machines. This allows the Network Address Translation (NAT) feature to work on the virtual machine and is usually the most reliable option (at least in my experience). The only exception to this is if I need a *stand-alone* virtual machine totally segregated from the internet, in which case I would use the *Host-only* option.

Comment: Thanks very much mono for your reply. I do believe that you are missing my point that I have an external wifi dongle that is passed via USB to the guest. I have updated my question with a clear images of this issue. So I have successfully connected in the guest and got a different IP from my host. Although I cannot connect to my works wifi portal so something is acting up and I wonder why :D